# Compute $\int_C\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$ where $\textbf{F}(x,y)=\langle y+x^2,y^2+x\rangle$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute $\int_C\textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$ where $\textbf{F}(x,y)=\langle y+x^2,y^2+x\rangle$ and $C$ is a smooth curve starting from $(1,0)$ to $(2,4).$

This may be a stupid question, but I just don't see it yet. How do I find $d\textbf{r}$?

Comment: $\textbf{r}=\langle x,y\rangle$, so $d\textbf{r}=\langle dx,dy\rangle$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point here is that for this question, you don't need to!  Notice that you haven't been given an explicit parameterization of your curve, or even an explicit description of your curve?

That should be a dead-giveaway that this integral is expected to be *independent of path* -- that is, that only the start and endpoint of your contour matter!

Another sign is that if you write $\mathbf{F}=\langle f,g\rangle$, then
$$
g_x-f_y=1-1=0.
$$
That tells you that this vector field is conservative, meaning that it can be written as the gradient of some function.

So: can you find a function $\phi(x,y)$ so that $\nabla \phi(x,y)=\langle y+x^2,y^2+x\rangle$? If you can, then by the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals you know that for any smooth curve $C$ from $(1,0)$ to $(2,4)$,
$$
\int_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\phi(2,4)-\phi(1,0).
$$

Comment: The third paragraph is misleading. This is only a necessary condition for $\mathbf F$ to be conservative, not sufficient unless you state extra hypotheses!

Comment: @TedShifrin While that's certainly correct, the fact is that in courses such as the one I assure you the OP is taking, those conditions are all but assumed and taken for granted.  (I should know -- I've been teaching that course for years, and the fact drives me nuts. :-) )

Comment: Me too, but in standard Calc 3 courses we do the usual counterexample, so it's not too much for you to make the correct statement here. I teach my students that it *might* be conservative and they have the hunting license to hunt for a potential function.